# selenium - find_element within list of <li> within<ul>

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
list_of_li = find_elements(by='xpath', value='//ul/*')

list_of_text_i_need = [x.find_element(by='xpath', value='//div/div/article/div/div/div/span').text for x in list_of_li]
```

This returns the proper number of values *len(list_of_li)* but every value in list_of_text_i_need is the .text of the very first li in list_of_li not the rest in the first list.

If I print the .text of list_of_li it gives me all the correct values that I'm trying to put into a list but when accessing it with the find_element by xpath it only finds the very first one.

Any help is of course appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `find_elements` to get all matching elements (rather than `find_element` which only returns one) on each element in `list_of_li`, and get the `text` of each of those elements with a nested list comprehension.

```py
[y.text for x in list_of_li for y in x.find_elements(by='xpath', value='//div/div/article/div/div/div/span')]
```

Comment: You blew my mind. I have no idea how this works but it does.

Comment: Any chance you can ELI5 how this works please?

Comment: @lexlikely Essentially, the equivalent nested loop without the list comprehension looks like this: https://pastebin.com/Vy9dRSsH

Comment: The main thing here is to call `find_elements` to get all the matching elements instead of `find_element` which only returns the first matching one.